# What is the best way to print position of items in the list of strings using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, selenium, web-scraping

I've started some web scraping things and I'm pretty new in python. I want to find position of a element in the list of strings in python. So far I've tried some if any statements but python always returns me "bool is not iterable". I'am using regex and I've managed to obtain valuable things and now want to display position of the matching string in list. When I use code from below I get an output like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(string_data)):
print(string_data[i])

<td class="kx o_1" data-bookmaker="16">
<td class="kx o_0" data-bookmaker="16">
<td class="kx o_2 winner" data-bookmaker="16">
```

What is to best way to find position of an item in list that matches word "winner".In my case it would be the second position if I count it from 0, but how can I do that?

Comment: do you need to know the position rather than just grab the result? What do you actually need as a result and is there an url to go with this?

Comment: Basically what I was trying to do is retrieving odds for betting from https://www.flashscore.com/ and then modifying data to help user navigate faster and make some kind of predictions based on odds.I needed this positions so I could know If winning position is 1, then I would have to search only first td and so on, but I would only display one "winning" odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

If you your list contains *exactly* string you want to match, eg:

```
import numpy as np
items = ['something', 'something else', 'winner']
winner_ids = np.where([item == 'winner' for item in items])
```

You mentioned [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) so here’s how you can match against a substring:

```
import numpy as np
items = ['something', 'something else', 'something containing winner']
winner_ids = np.where([re.findall('winner', item) for item in items])
```

Be careful that `np.where` will return a list of items. In the two examples, `winner_ids` is `(array([2]),)`. If you’re expecting to find *a single* winner, you can then do:

```
winner_id = winner_ids[0][0]
```

And now `winner_id` is `2` as you expect.

Comment: oh man! I never knew about `np.where`. This is great. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a cleaner, shorter way to do this, but we can write out a nice loop to track the element position, search the list of `td` elements, and once it encounters `winner`, print out that position:

```
position = 0 # start position at index 0

td_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td") # get elements to iterate
# td_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[contains(@class, 'kx')]")
# ^ this is an alternate selector, in case tag_name is too generic.

# iterate td elements, searching for 'winner' in the class
for element in td_elements:

    # check if class attribute contains winner
    if ("winner" in element.get_attribute("class")):
        print(str(position) # winner! print position of element

    else: position++ # increment position if we did not find a winner
```

Hope this helps a bit. Another user posted a solution using `BeautifulSoup`, which seems to work well if you are already using BS. I am providing a pure Selenium example, in case that is what you are using here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `enumerate` to return the index value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<td class="kx o_1" data-bookmaker="16">
<td class="kx o_0" data-bookmaker="16">
<td class="kx o_2 winner" data-bookmaker="16">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for idx, item in enumerate(soup.find_all('td')):
    print (idx, item['class'])
```

**Output:**

```
0 ['kx', 'o_1']
1 ['kx', 'o_0']
2 ['kx', 'o_2', 'winner']
```

And to just return if it has winner:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(soup.find_all('td')):
    if 'winner' in item['class']:
        print (idx, item['class'])
```